# iPhone, Using tableview in existing view based project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to add table view in my view based application, which has a single delegate and some other controllers for different views. Now I want to add a table view with in which on selecting a row a new table view will be opened and in the second tableview selecting a row will show the details related to that row.

Please tell me how can I achieve that, if there is any tutorial related to this then please suggest.

As I have found the tutorials are navigation based. I want as I described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See its Very Simple and Easy.... :-

Just go to ur **FirstViewController.xib** Drag and Drop the tableView on the View. Now in .H file write its delegate like `<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`

Now write `IBOutlet UITableView *myFirstTable;`

in .m file :-

Implement the methods of TableView Required By you.Now in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method write the Code for going to the Another View like

```
SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self PresentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

So untill this you will see the SecondViewController on click on Any row cell of FirstTable in the firstViewController.

**AND YES DONT FORGET TO SET THE DELEGATE IN YOUR XIB**

Now Similarly Implement for second Table. Drag n drop the Table View on your View implement its delegate in .h file(SecondViewController.h)

Implement the Methods of table View Delegates you want and again in **didselectRowAtIndexPath** method write the Code you want onTapping on the row of a Cell...

i Hope you got this... if not Tell me i will try to be more clear... or provide some Direct code...
but if it helps then Please Accept the Answer and Upvote.. :))

Comment: I am not getting it, its confusing! actually in one of my view i will click on a button and a tableview should be opened than in that table view when i click on a row it should go to another table and than that table rows should show a view which will have the details like CAR GROUPS (Table View) > CARS LIST (Table View) > CAR DETAILS

Comment: You are talking about a navigation controller. This method does not implement a navigation controller. Check Apple's sample code for the proper way to implement a navigation controller with a table view.

Comment: @OmerKhan :- Welcome dude... I am too Happy :))

Answer (score 1):

You need a navigation controller to work with different controller. View based and Navigation based app are just template for your project. You can add the same code that in a Navigation based project in a view based project.

Just add a navigation controller to access to the pushViewController method. For a good sample about that, create a Navigation based project and read the code (and the MainWindows.xib configuration)